# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/sdk_release.kotlin_module'

Tags: android

I get this error when trying to import a dependency. The stripe SDK to be precise.

```
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:12.5.0'
```

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/sdk_release.kotlin_module'

Removing the implementation removes the problem, I've tried solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license) without any success.

Here's a more detailed build error.

> com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/sdk_release.kotlin_module'
>       at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms.lambda$acceptOnlyOne$2(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:75)
>       at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms.lambda$select$3(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:100)
>       at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMergerOutputs$1.create(IncrementalFileMergerOutputs.java:86) ...

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Google Language API results in DuplicateRelativeFileException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671353/adding-google-language-api-results-in-duplicaterelativefileexception)

Comment: @AndreClassen Sadly not, I have tried this and just tried again to be sure. Super weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers were close, I had to this to the **app/build.gradle** to get it excluded properly.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/sdk_release.kotlin_module'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to add following code to your `app/build.gralde`

```
android {
...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I feel like this should have worked, but it didn't, I posted the solution, thanks for the answer regardless

Comment: This wouldn't work because it's missing the META-INF path. If I'm not mistaken, `**/*.kotlin_module` should have been the wildcard answer.